# Estimation of a combinatoric formula

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Assume $n\ge m$, what is the estimation of

$$\sum_{k_1+\dots +k_m\,=\,n,\\ k_1\ge 1,\,\dots,\,k_m\ge 1} C_n^{k_1,\dots,k_m} \left(\frac{1}{k_1}+\frac{1}{k_2}+\dots +\frac{1}{k_m} \right)$$

where $C_n^{k_1,\dots,k_m}$ is the multinomial coefficient.

I am particularly interested in an upper bound, the tighter the better.

Comment: It is $n!$ times a coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x)^m$ where $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty x^j/(j\cdot j!)=\int_0^x (e^t-1)/t dt$. This allows to apply saddle point method etc.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Is it? The coefficient you are considering is $\sum_{k_1+\ldots+k_m=n}n!\prod_{i=1}^m\frac1{k_i!k_i}$, not the one from the question

Comment: So it's rather $n!m\cdot[x^n]((e^x-1)^{m-1}\cdot\int_0^x(e^t-1)\,dt/t)$

Comment: Of course, you are correct. Still saddle point method is applied.

Comment: What kind of estimation do you want: asymptotics? upper bound? lower bound? If a bound, then with what properties? Also, under what condition(s) on $m$ and $n$: if (say) $n\to\infty$, then how does $m$ vary with $n$?

Comment: edited @IosifPinelis

Comment: @IosifPinelis，see the comment below.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\renewcommand{\b}{\binom}$Here we will express the sum in question as an ordinary integral of an ordinary sum, which is much easier to analyze than the original expression -- which was a sum over an $m$-dimensional integer simplex, involving multinomial coefficients.

We will also analyze the simpler expression in the case when $m\to\infty$ and $n\ge cm\ln m$ for a real constant $c>1$. Then the resulting upper bound is optimal up to a constant factor.

---

For positive integers $n$ and $m$, let
\begin{equation*}
    K^0:=\{k=(k_1,\dots,k_m)\in\Z_+^m\colon k_1+\dots+k_m=n\}, 
\end{equation*}
where $\Z_+:=\{0,1,\dots\}$, and
\begin{equation*}
    K:=\{k\in K^0\colon k_1\ge1,\dots,k_m\ge1\}.  
\end{equation*}
Then, by the exchangeability of the $k_i$'s, the sum in question is
\begin{equation*}
    S_{n,m}:=m\sum_{k\in K}\b nk\frac1{k_m}, \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \b nk:=\b n{k_1,\dots,k_m}=\frac{n!}{k_1!\dots,k_m!}. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    S_{n,m}=m\int_0^1\frac{dx}x\,S(K), \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    S(J):=\sum_{k\in J}\b nk x^{k_m}
\end{equation*}
for all $J\in P([m])$, where in turn $P([m])$ is the power set of the set $[m]:=\{1,\dots,m\}$.
For $J\in P([m])$, let also
\begin{equation*}
    K_J:=\{k\in K^0\colon k_j=0\ \forall j\in J\}, 
\end{equation*}
so that $K_\emptyset=K^0$ and $K_{[m]}=\emptyset$ (since $n\ge1$). So, by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Other_formulas),
\begin{equation*}
    S(K)=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j\sum_{|J|=j}S(K_J), \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
where $\sum_{|J|=j}$ denotes the summation over all $J\in P([m])$ of cardinality $|J|=j$.

Next, for each $J\in P([m])$ with $|J|=j$ we have the following:

- If $m\in J$, then $S(K_J)=(m-j)^n$.
- If $m\notin J$, then $S(K_J)=(x+m-j-1)^n$.

Also, there are $\b{m-1}{j-1}$ sets $J\in P([m])$ with $|J|=j$ such that $m\in J$; and there are $\b{m-1}{j}$ sets $J\in P([m])$ with $|J|=j$ such that $m\notin J$. So, by \eqref{2},
\begin{align*}
    S(K)&=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j\Big[\b{m-1}{j-1}(m-j)^n+\b{m-1}{j}(x+m-j-1)^n\Big] \\ 
    &=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j\b{m-1}{j}\big[(x+m-j-1)^n-(m-j-1)^n\big];
\end{align*}
here we took into account that $\b{m-1}{-1}=0$ and $m-m=0$ and $n\ge1$. So, in view of \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
    S_{n,m}=m\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j\b{m-1}{j}I_{n,m}, \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{align*}
    I_{n,m}&:=\int_0^1\frac{dx}x\,\big[(x+m-j-1)^n-(m-j-1)^n\big] \\ 
    &:=\int_0^1 dx\,\ln\frac1x\;n(x+m-j-1)^{n-1},
\end{align*}
via integration by parts. So, by \eqref{3},
\begin{equation*}
    S_{n,m}=m\int_0^1 dx\,\ln\frac1x\;\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j\b{m-1}{j}n(x+m-j-1)^{n-1}. \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}

The latter expression for $S_{n,m}$, which is an ordinary integral of an ordinary sum, is much easier to analyze than the original expression \eqref{0} for $S_{n,m}$ (which was a sum over an $m$-dimensional integer simplex, involving multinomial coefficients).

Specifics of analysis of the expression for $S_{n,m}$ in \eqref{4} depend on how $m$ varies with $n$.
For instance, suppose that
\begin{equation*}
n\ge m\ln m, \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation*}
which seems a natural assumption.
Then for
\begin{equation*}
    a_j:=a_{n,m;j}(x):=\b{m-1}{j}n(x+m-j-1)^{n-1}
\end{equation*}
and $x\in(0,1)$ and $j\in\{0,\dots,m-2\}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    r_j:=\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}=\Big(1-\frac1{x+m-j-1}\Big)^{n-1}\frac{m-j-1}{j+1} \\ 
    \le\Big(1-\frac1m\Big)^{n-1}(m-1)\le m e^{-n/m}\le1.
\end{equation*}
So, the $a_j$'s are nonincreasing in $j\in\{0,\dots,m-1\}$.
So, by \eqref{4},
\begin{align*}
    S_{n,m}&=m\int_0^1 dx\,\ln\frac1x\;\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}(-1)^j a_{n,m;j}(x) \\ 
    &\le m\int_0^1 dx\,\ln\frac1x\;a_{n,m;0}(x) \\ 
    &=m\int_0^1 dx\,\ln\frac1x\;n(x+m-1)^{n-1}. 
    \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align*}

To upper-bound the latter integral, take any $b\in(0,1)$.
Since $\ln\frac1x$ is decreasing and $n(x+m-1)^{n-1}$ is increasing in $x\in(0,1)$, by the [Chebyshev integral inequality](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevIntegralInequality.html) we have
\begin{align*}
    &\int_0^b dx\,\ln\frac1x\;n(x+m-1)^{n-1} \\ 
    & \le\frac1b\,\int_0^b dx\,\ln\frac1x\;\int_0^b dx\,n(x+m-1)^{n-1} \\ 
    & =\ln\frac1b\;[(b+m-1)^{n}-(m-1)^{n}] \\ 
    & \le\ln\frac1b\;(b+m-1)^{n} \\ 
    & \le\ln\frac1b\;m^n\Big(1+\frac{b-1}m\Big)^{n} \\ 
    &\le\ln\frac1b\;m^n e^{-(1-b)n/m}.  
    \tag{7}\label{7}
\end{align*}
Since $\frac{\ln(1/x)}{1-x}$ is decreasing in $x\in(0,1)$, with
\begin{equation*}
    C_b:=\frac{\ln(1/b)}{1-b}
\end{equation*}
we get
\begin{align*}
    &\int_b^1 dx\,\ln\frac1x\;n(x+m-1)^{n-1} \\ 
    & \le C_b\int_b^1 dx\,(1-x)\;n(x+m-1)^{n-1} \\ 
    & \le C_b\int_0^1 dx\,(1-x)\;n(x+m-1)^{n-1} \\ 
    & = C_b\frac mn[m^n-(m-1)^n-n(m-1)^{n-1}]\le C_b\frac{m^{n+1}}n. 
    \tag{8}\label{8}
\end{align*}
Collecting \eqref{6}, \eqref{7}, and \eqref{8}, we get
\begin{align*}
    S_{n,m}&\le B_{n,m}:=m^{n+1}\Big(\frac{C_b}n+\ln\frac1b\;e^{-(1-b)n/m}\Big).
    \tag{9}\label{9}
\end{align*}

If we now strengthen condition \eqref{5} to
\begin{equation*}
n\ge cm\ln m \tag{5a}\label{5a}
\end{equation*}
for any real constant $c>\frac1{1-b}$, then for the bound $B_{n,m}$ in \eqref{9} we will have
\begin{equation*}
    B_{n,m}\sim C_b \frac{m^{n+1}}n 
\end{equation*}
as $m\to\infty$.

This may be compared with the following trivial bound on $S_{n,m}$: in view of \eqref{0},
\begin{equation*}
    S_{n,m}\le m\sum_{k\in K^0}\b nk=m^{n+1}. \tag{10}\label{10} 
\end{equation*}

So, given \eqref{5a}, the bound $B_{n,m}$ in \eqref{9} improves the trivial bound in \eqref{10} by a factor $\asymp n$.
Following the lines of the above reasoning and noting that $\ln\frac1x>1-x$ for $x\in(0,1)$, one can see that this factor cannot be further improved, at least given \eqref{5a}.

---

Note also that, again assuming \eqref{5a}, the bound $B_{n,m}$ in \eqref{9} is better than the bound conjectured at the end of [Brendan McKay's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461227/36721) by a factor $\asymp m$.

Comment: ，what if you don't pose $n>cmlnm$ assumption? In this case，if it will return to Brendan McKay's result?

Comment: @HaoYu : As I [wrote two weeks ago](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461169/estimation-of-a-combinatoric-formula?noredirect=1#comment1196172_461169), the good bounds will depend on how $m$ varies with $n$. You never specified that. One of the main points of the current answer was to express the sum in question as an ordinary integral of an ordinary sum, which is much easier to analyze than the original expression. I hoped you would appreciate that.

Comment: Previous comment continued: At this point, given that the answer is already very long, I suggest you finalize this matter, and then post further/specialized questions separately.

Comment: I only assume $n\ge m$, it is still not easy at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Given that an upper bound is requested, here is one. By symmetry one can replace $\frac1{k_1}+\cdots+\frac1{k_m}$ by $\frac1{k_1}$ and multiply everything by $m$. Now do the sum over $k_1$ (which I'll call $k$) separately.
$$\begin{align*}X &= m \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac 1k \sum_{k_2+\cdots+k_m=n;\, k_2\ge 1,\ldots,k_m\ge 1} \binom{n}{k,k_2,\ldots,k_m}\\
 &= m \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac 1k \binom nk
   \sum_{k_2+\cdots+k_m=n;\, k_2\ge 1,\ldots,k_m\ge 1} \binom{n-k}{k_2,\ldots,k_m}.
\end{align*}$$
The last sum has no closed form, but it is bounded above by dropping the conditions $k_2\ge 1,\ldots,k_m\ge 1$. Using the multinomial theorem,
$$ X \le m \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac 1k \binom nk (m-1)^{n-k}.$$
This will be very accurate if $m$ is not too large, as the additional terms we added will be negligible then.
Unfortunately we now have a hypergeometric function and I don't know of a sharp upper bound.

When $m$ is not very large the sequence is approximately gaussian with mode around $k=\frac nm$, so expanding around that point will provide an asymptotic expression. Continuing by guesswork, the sum should be about $\frac mn$ times the sum without the $\frac 1k$, which gives an estimate
$$ \frac {m^2}{n} \bigl( m^n - (m-1)^n\bigr).$$
All this needs checking.